Regularity of homogeneous random field in $\mathbb R^2$ and absolute continuity. Has this been generalized to the $n$-dimensional case?
What I am talking about is a rather old mathematical paper, published in Russian, from 1957. The name of the paper is “О линейном экстраполировании дискретного однородного случайного пoля”.
I cannot speak Russian, but according to online translator, Theorem 1 of this papers makes the connection between the regularity of a homogeneous random field in $\mathbb R^2$ and absolute continuity. It says:
In order of a homogeneous random field $x(s,t)$ to be regular, it is necessary and sufficient to satisfy:
$$ (1) \qquad dF_x (\lambda, \mu) \text{ and } dF_x (\lambda, \mu) \, d\mu $$ are absolutely continuous to each other on $ \lambda, \mu \in [-\pi, \pi].$ $$\quad (2) \ldots$$
The second condition is not important right now for me, the first condition about the absolute continuity is very interesting though. $F_x (\lambda, \mu)$ as far as I've understood is the "normalized distribution function" of that random field.
As you can see, this result is for two dimensions. What I am interested in, is: Was this result proven for the general $n$-dimensional case?
Because that paper is from 1957, I assume that there has been done something at least. But I don't know how to find it, because as I said, I cannot speak Russian and thus don't know how to specifically look for it.
I appreciate any help, thanks!
